# Input of 2D array (-1 for end of row input, -2 for end of 2D array input) problem

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array, scanf

Hello everyone and thanks for taking your time to answer,

Several times while practicing I came across a problem where I need to input a 2D array(matrix). In the exercise it says that I should enter -1 when I finish entering a row (to get to the next one), and inputting -2 signals that the matrix input is finished.

I tried doing something like this which I could use for most of my exercises but it does not work and I can't seem to find the reason. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,matrix[100][100];
    int m,n;

    for(i=0; i<100; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<100; j++)
    {

        scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);

        if(matrix[i][j]==-2) {
                m=i+1;  //After I enter -2, the matrix dimensions should be 
                n=j-1;  // "m" and "n", but for some reason once I enter this
                        // if statement, "i" has to be incremented by 1 
                        // and "j" has  to be decremented by 1 for it to work

                i=1000; // i use this to get out of nested loop
            break;
        }
        if(mat1[i][j]==-1)
        {
            i++; // once the user inputs -1, I increase "i"(next row), 

            j=0; //and here I set the "column" count to 0


        }
    }

    }



    for(i=0; i<m; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++) {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }




    return 0;
}
```

So, when I have an input like this:

```
1 2 3 -1
1 2 3 -1
1 2 3 -2
```

The matrix(printed on the screen) looks like:

```
1 2 3 
0 1 2 
0 1 2
```

Does anyone have any idea why this does not work as intended? I can't seem to find it!

Comment: At least the variable i is increased twice in the outer loop and in an if statement.

Comment: How else should I jump to the next "row" of the matrix from the inner loop?

Answer (score -1):

The code in the question attempts to control `i` and `j` with these statements:

```
for(i=0; i<100; i++) {
for(j=0; j<100; j++)
```

and also with these statements:

```
if(mat1[i][j]==-1)
    {
        i++; // once the user inputs -1, I increase "i"(next row), 
        j=0; //and here I set the "column" count to 0
    }
```

**These conflict.** When “-1” is entered, the latter statements reset `j` to zero, but then program control flows to the end of the inner `for` loop. That `for` loop, `for(j=0; j<100; j++)`, increments `j` and continues execution. Now `j` is one instead of the zero you intended.

Instead of trying to control `i` and `j` with two different pieces of code, unify it. You can write code that uses a loop with no adjustments to `i` and `j` and make the adjustments on a case-by-case basis:

```
i = 0; j = 0;
do
{
    int input;
    scanf("%d", &input);

    if (input == -2)
    {
        // At the end of the matrix, record the dimensions and leave the loop.
        m = i+1;
        n = j;
        break;
    }
    else if (input == -1)
    {
        // At the end of a row, move to the start of the next row.
        ++i;
        j = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        // Otherwise, record a single element and move to the next element.
        matrix[i][j] = input;
        ++j;
    }
} while (1);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, it is comprehensible and easy to understand for a newbie. I understand where I was making mistakes. Thanks again. +1

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: When substituted into the code in the question in place of its `for` loops, the resulting source code compiles with Apple LLVM 10.0.1 with clang-1001.0.46.4, executes on macOS 10.14.6, and produces the desired output when given the input shown in the question. What exactly do you think is invalid?

Comment: @EricPostpischil A compiled code does not mean a valid code.:) The code at least does not take into account the upper bounds of the original array.. Moreover the number of entered data for a row can vary from row to row.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Those complaints are unrelated to the question asked by the OP and do not make a program invalid. They amount to limits on its usefulness—it cannot be used for arbitrarily or irregularly sized arrays—but the code is valid for the limited circumstances the OP is intending it for. Keep in mind Stack Overflow is **not** a code-writing service—answers are intended to answer a **specific** question, not necessarily to deliver a completely reformulated program solving all potential problems and teaching the questioner all about programming at one time.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are mistaken. You presented code that will not work in many cases. It is just an invalid code.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: What do you mean by “invalid”? Unacceptable to the compiler? A violation of some constraint of the C standard? A failure to conform to the program’s specification?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Unfortunately, you are using imprecise or incorrect terminology. The program is valid: It conforms to its specifications. It is not specified to work with arbitrary sizes or irregular row lengths. It serves the purposes **set for it**. Your desire that it work with sizes beyond 100 or irregular row lengths are things **you added**, not requirements stated by the OP. There is **no reason** a program **must** work in all situations. Sometimes we want a program to reject inputs outside various parameters, sometimes we do not. That is a matter of choice, not validity.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Each row gets values until -1 is entered. There nothing said that each row will have the same number of inputs.  Otherwise there is no reason to mention -1. Moreover for example -2 can follow -1. You also does not take this into account. Your code just a bad code.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: These constraints are ones you have added, not ones requested by the OP. And, as I stated, the purpose is **to answer the specific question the OP has**, not to solve all of their problems and teach them everything about programming.

Answer (score -3):

Your code does not make sense.

In fact all input is processed in one inner loop. However this inner loop is executed until `-2` will be entered. So the outer loop is redundant.

Within the inner loop the iteration for a next "row" starts from `1`

```
for(j=0; j<100; j++)
                ^^^
{
    //...

    if(mat1[i][j]==-1)
    {
        i++; // once the user inputs -1, I increase "i"(next row), 

        j=0; //and here I set the "column" count to 0
        ^^^^

    }
```

Because after setting it to zero in the if statement it is increased in the loop.

Take into account that in general the number of values for a row can varies.

When a sentinel value is used (and in your assignment there are used even two sentinel values) it always mean that the input can contain a variable number of items. Your program should process this situation correctly. Otherwise you have to count the number of entered values in each row and if the numbers are different issue an error. But this will make your program more complicated.

Also you ignores the case when `-2` can follow `-1`.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the data input can be organized.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 100 };
    int a[N][N] = { 0 };
    size_t m = 0, n = 0;

    for ( ; m < N; m++ )
    {
        size_t i = 0;
        int value = 0;

        for ( ; i < N && value != -1 && value != -2; i++ )
        {
            scanf( "%d", &value );

            if ( value != -1 && value != -2 ) a[m][i] = value;
            else break;
        }

        if ( n < i ) n = i;

        if ( value == - 2 )
        {
            if ( i != 0 ) ++m;
            break;
        }
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If the input is

```
1 2 3 -1
4 5 6 -1
7 8 9 -2
```

then the program outputs the following matrix

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

Or for example if the input looks like

```
1 2 3 4 -1
5 6 -1
-2
```

Then the output is

```
1 2 3 4 
5 6 0 0
```

In the program `m` means the number of rows and `n` means the number of column in the result matrix.

Comment: @KBlr It is an improved code that takes into account all peculirities that was not taken into account by the author of the question. It is the best code presented in the answers.  It is your problem if you do not understand this.

Comment: The code in this answer fails to include `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: The code in this answer fails to check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: The code in this answer fails to recognize when an input row exceeds the allotted length, and it continues silently to the next row instead of warning the user.

Comment: The code in this answer fails to recognize when the input contains more rows than the allotted number and continues execution without warning the user.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It is not redundant because without it i will be increased.

Comment: For irregular row lengths, the code in this answer provides a default value of zero, but it is unknown what a correct default value is or whether any default value should be provided rather than NaN-type information.

Comment: The use of −1 and −2 as sentinels indicates negative numbers are not proper data for the array, but the code is this answer fails to perform any error handling for negative values.

Comment: Overall, it is abundantly clear the code in this answer is “invalid” as defined by its author.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I agree with your last comment but I do not agree with the previous comment. Negative numbers may be entered (at least there is nothing said about such a restriction) except -1 and -2.